# Sql Server 2008 FullText not indexing in background

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

Is there any way of doing an incremental population not in background? I want to create a job that will do a incremental population and when it is finished, the job will set a "end date" in a table. For now I need to have 2 jobs, one that actually stats the population and another one that will check if the population is done every X minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no way of doing that. I just talked to a msdn guy about that. I will implement that verification in my application.